# PHP - Issue update db field with add to existing value

Tags: php, database

I have db field say like this :
For example, lets say we have table like this

```
    +--------------+
    | some_table   |
    +--------------+
    | name  | text |
    +--------------+
    |  a    | b    |
    +--------------+
```

I want to update without delete existing value. say i want to update field `name` and `text` with adding `" add"` , so value of field now is  `b add`

I try use query :  `mysql_query("update table set text=text+' add' where name='a' ");`

Can you analyze this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `CONCAT()` method:

```
UPDATE table SET text = CONCAT(text, ' add') WHERE name = 'a'
```

The following should also work:

```
UPDATE table SET text = text ' add' WHERE name = 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

COncatenate strings with CONCAT function:

`mysql_query("update table set text = CONCAT(text, ' add') where name='a' ");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MySQL CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
mysql_query("update table set text=concat(text, ' add') where name='a' ");
```